# Term for someone who wears a burqa

Tags: single-word-requests, loanwords

A person who wears a hijab is sometimes called a hijabi, a person who wears a niqab is sometimes called a niqabi. Is there an equivalent term for someone who wears a burqa? According to Wiktionary hijab, hijabi, and niqab are directly from Arabic, and burqa is indirectly derived from Arabic, which is why I suspect there is an equivalent term.

The word would be used like this:

> All the newspapers had photos of the (word for burqa wearer), but none had photos of the person criticising her.

Comment: I would say "person".  Or, if it was not considered being too presumptive, "woman".

Comment: It seems that 'burqa wearer' is not uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

There is some support for using "burqai" or "burkai", but it is extremely rare:

[Islam in India and the Middle East](https://books.google.com/books?id=ROyV1HpycMQC&q=%22burqai%22%20%22face%20veil%22&dq=%22burqai%22%20%22face%20veil%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi97Yuem_DVAhXM5yYKHZMAAuYQ6AEIKDAA) (1955) says:

> hero, Mokanna, known as Hakim Burqai or the physician with face veil,...

[A History of Persia, Volume 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=lm_UAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=Hakim%20Burkai&source=bl&ots=NcqyJHbAxG&sig=6A2oSglQ0_0HBXhwEvlUybXj-R0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3z-_voPDVAhVkw4MKHZqHCYsQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Hakim%20Burkai&f=false) (1915) says:

> Its hero, Mokanna, known as Hakim Burkai, or " the Physician with the face-veil," was born at Karez, which is now a squalid village on the road between Meshed

Similarly [The history of the Arabians, under the government of the Caliphs](https://books.google.com/books?id=Haw2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA35&dq=%22burkai%22%20%22burka%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVpL7HmfDVAhWH14MKHQVNCCYQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22burkai%22%20%22burka%22&f=false) (1758) says:

> a Mussulman, called Hakem, and sirnamed Burkai, from the Arabic word Burka, which signifies a Masque

and the same book earlier (1750) [in French](https://books.google.com/books?id=DOhOAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA49&dq=%22burkai%22%20%22burka%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVpL7HmfDVAhWH14MKHQVNCCYQ6AEIQDAF#v=onepage&q=%22burkai%22%20%22burka%22&f=false):

> Musulman nommé Hakem, & surnomme Burkai , du mot Arabe Burka, qui signifie un masque.

Comment: Those are all surnames for one person though

Comment: @Unrelated right, those 4 references (an several other references) are all talking about the surname origin of that specific person, who covered his face to hide severe injuries.

Comment: Which could be helpful, but to answer the original question we need examples of burqai being used generally and generically